# How to fill input when select change, in php or js?

Tags: javascript, html

This code should automatically set the department if the course is chosen

```js
function getDept() {
  var x = document.getElementById("course").value;
  if (x == "BSIT"){
    document.getElementById("department").value = "CIT";
  }
  document.getElementById("department").value=x;
}

document.getElementById("course").addEventListener("change". getDept)
```

```html
<label for="course">Course</label>

<select class="form-select" id="course" name="course" required>
  <option value="">Select Course</option> 
  <option value="BSIT">BSIT</option>
  <option value="BSN">BSN</option>
  <option value="BSA">BSA</option>
  <option value="BSBA">BSBA</option>
  <option value="BSHM">BSHM</option>
  <option value="BSGE">BSGE</option>
  <option value="BSCRIM">BSCRIM</option>
  <option value="BAPolSci">BAPolSci</option>
  <option value="BSM">BSM</option>
</select>

<label for="department">Department</label>
<input class="form-control"  id="department" name="department" readonly>
```

Example.
User choose BSIT then it will automatically fill the input department, it should filled with CIT.

Comment: The code as currently shown, shows a clear error message in the browser console.

Comment: if you check the console you will see the error, you mistakenly added a dot instead of a comma in the eventlistener `.addEventListener("change", getDept)`

Answer (score 0):

There's two problems in your code. Firstly, the correct separator for arguments in JS is the comma (`,`), not period (`.`), so your event handler should be bound like this:

```
document.getElementById("course").addEventListener("change", getDept)
```

Secondly, you set the value of the `department` within the `if` condition, but then you immediately overwrite it it again outside of the condition. You need to amend the logic flow to make the setting of the value exclusive to either state of your condition. This can be done most simply by using an `else` statement:

```js
const course = document.querySelector('#course');
const department = document.querySelector('#department');

function getDept() {
  var selectedCourse = course.value;
  if (selectedCourse == "BSIT") {
    department.value = "CIT";
  } else {
    department.value = selectedCourse;
  }
  
  // alternative: ternary version of the if statement
  // department.value = selectedCourse === 'BSIT' ? 'CIT' : selectedCourse;
}

course.addEventListener("change", getDept)
```

```html
<label for="course">Course</label>

<select class="form-select" id="course" name="course" required>
  <option value="">Select Course</option>
  <option value="BSIT">BSIT</option>
  <option value="BSN">BSN</option>
  <option value="BSA">BSA</option>
  <option value="BSBA">BSBA</option>
  <option value="BSHM">BSHM</option>
  <option value="BSGE">BSGE</option>
  <option value="BSCRIM">BSCRIM</option>
  <option value="BAPolSci">BAPolSci</option>
  <option value="BSM">BSM</option>
</select>

<label for="department">Department</label>
<input class="form-control" id="department" name="department" readonly>
```

Comment: What is the reason behind changing OP's more specific getElementById('course') to the less specific querySelector('#course')?

Comment: Personal preference. But the main point there is to not repeatedly call the DOM to retrieve elements.